# Set deep linking URI dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

The Android [deep linking docs](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html) indicate that the URI should be set in the AndroidManifest file.

Is there any way to set this value dynamically at run time, instead of in the AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. You cannot add an `IntentFilter` to an activity at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you cannot edit the intent filter but you can enable/disable the component that's associated with that filter.
For example you do not want to intercept http://yoursite.com ACTION_VIEW Intent until your user is authenticated. To do that you have to set `android:enabled="false"` and later in the end of the authentication you should enable that component using PackageManager:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, ActivityC.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 0);
```